# Set ReactiveDict() variable inside of custom event function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I try to set a ReactiveDict-variable on a custom event inside of `on()`, but I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateDictionary' of null`.

The second question is, if it would make sense to define the `ReactiveDict()` in `onRendered`?

```
Template.something.onCreated(function() {
    this.templateDictionary = new ReactiveDict();
});

Template.something.onRendered(function() {
    anything.on({
        'element:mouseover': function(elementView, event){
            Template.instance().templateDictionary.set( 'showExtraFields', true );
        }
    });
});

Template.something.helpers({
    anything: function() {
        var result = Template.instance().templateDictionary.get( 'showExtraFields' );
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Dont call `Template.instance()` into an `onRendered` function. Use `this` instead. If your error comes from the helper, check if `templateDictionary` is not in `Template.instance().data` instead of simply `Template.instance()`. Just log it and look into the object tree.

Answer (score 2):

Put instance reference inside onRendered function.   Not inside another function.   Scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `anything.on` is, but try this:

```
Template.something.onRendered(function() {
    anything.on({
        'element:mouseover': (elementView, event) => {
            this.templateDictionary.set( 'showExtraFields', true );
        }
    });
});
```

Use the ES6, Luke!